# Creating Mongoose organization/class structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am building a web application with Node.js, Express, and Mongoose/MongoDB.

One question I had was how do I properly organize and structure methods related to Mongoose. I need to call Mongoose functionality inside my routes, but all examples show using Mongoose calls without structuring separate files or classes with prototypes.

IE. Setting up a schema and calling mongoose in routes

```
SiteModel.find({}, function(err, docs) {
if (!err){ 
    console.log(docs);
    process.exit();
} else {throw err;}
});
```

I would like to put mongoose CRUD functions inside helper files related to logic and functionality and call them in my routes. When I use separate class methods with mongoose, no value is returned (Or due to the async nature I am unable to use the result)

```
//Router file
var myService =  require('../helpers/ServiceStatus');

router.get('/', authService.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){

   var serviceObject = new myService(); //Initialize class with Mongoose functions

   async.parallel({
       modelAFind: function(cb){
           //Mongoose class method is called
           var response= serviceObject.getAllServiceDetails(); 
           cb(null, response);
       },
       modelBFind: function(cb){
           cb(null, 2); //filler
       }
   }, function(results){
       console.log("Results of query: " + results);
   });
```

Snippet from my Mongoose class where I create a service object:

```
//ServiceStatus.js
//Constructor
function ServiceStatus() {

}

ServiceStatus.prototype.getAllServiceDetails = function(){

    var query = SiteModel.find({});
    var promise = query.exec();

    promise.then(function (doc) {
        return doc;
    });
};
```

What is the best way to deal with async, structure separate helper files with Mongoose logic and call them in routes: promises, functions with callbacks, etc? Thanks.

*Edit - Added Schema File

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// set up a mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('SiteModel', new Schema({

    id: String,
    service: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    status: String,
    settings: Object,
    lastCheck: String

}

,{
    timestamps: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there's a couple key rules of thumb you're missing, before we even get into the "best" way to organize your code.

1. When you're dealing with async methods, you have to always treat
   them (and their calling code) as async.  In your example, your
   `getAllServiceDetails()` function neither returns a promise nor
   executes a callback, so you lose that context.
2. Using both Promises and Callbacks in the same logic stack adds
   cognitive load to your brain; try and stick with one style or the
   other to the greatest extent possible.

As for the best way to organize, I'd look strongly at *not* pulling out a whole Service class in this case, and instead look at writing a mongoose plugin, or simply extending the mongoose schema itself.  Plugins are more useful if you're going to write the same code for multiple models, so I'll assume you're not in this case and continue with examples for only SiteSchema.  You don't show your schema code here so I'm not sure what you're really saving by not simply calling `SiteModel.find(...)` in your routing code, but for arguments sake you could either do:

```
SiteSchema.statics.list = function(cb) {
  SiteSchema.find({}, cb);
}
```

Which saves you from having to pass in the empty object in the calling code, but that calling code will still have to look like this:

```
/** snip **/
modelAFind: function(cb){
       //Mongoose class method is called
       var response= serviceObject.list(cb); 
   },
```

If you're using one of the most recent versions of node, you also have access to the async/await syntax, which might be more to your liking.  Note my example isn't tested, but it should look something like this:

```
SiteSchema.statics.list = async function() { // note the 'async' keyword 
  // latest versions of Mongoose, this returns a Promoise
  return SiteSchema.find({});
}
```

Then your consuming code can be

```
/** snip **/
modelAFind: function(cb){
       //Mongoose class method is called
       var response= await serviceObject.list(); // note 'await' keyword
       cb(null, response);
   },
```

Also note that I didn't add error handling; with async/await you just use try...catch.

Comment: Hi Paul, this is great information. I have attached the schema file for my model. For specific "getter" and "setter" queries, would you write all of the functions in the Mongoose schema rather than separate files?

Comment: Yes, definitely would do that. I only create service classes for logic that spans multiple models.